# What type of gas generator to run a dump pump, fridge, and 3 small appliances

Tags: generator

I need backup power to:
 - continuously run a sump pump for 4-5 hours 
 - continuously run A fridge
 - as needed run small appliances like coffee maker, electronics

Comment: Thanks everyone! I appreciate the honest replies

Comment: You might consider a dual fuel generator (one that can run on gasoline or propane). I like propane because it doesn't go bad like gasoline can over time.   Fuel stabilizers help gasoline, but propane doesn't have a shelf life.

Comment: @george Anderson Since the op did not provide much in wattage needed I think your answer may be of more honest value. To provide a real answer we would need the size of the sump pump 120v or 240v? We could guess on the coffee maker being on a 15 amp circuit the same as the fridge. Other Electronics is way to broad also so without more detail I like your answer the best. The op did not upvote anything but said thanks so the answer doesn’t help others, VTC.

Comment: I didn't bother with wattage because that was already discussed and I assumed (maybe incorrectly!), that it was obviously a consideration...just meant to suggest a dual fuel generator (of the desired capacity), because propane doesn't go bad over time like gasoline does.

Answer (score 1):

1/2 HP Sump Pump - 1000W Run but 2000-4000W startup
Refrigerator - 250W run but 1000-1500W startup
Coffee maker - 500W
Electronics?  You didn't specify.

So as long as your fridge and your sump pump don't startup at the same time, you could get by with a 4000W generator.  A 5000W would give you a bit of margin.

As far as run time, it depends on the fuel capacity of the generator.  You will want to keep extra fuel on hand if the outage lasts longer than the fuel tank capacity of the generator.

To be legal you will either need to run cords to each individual unit or install a lockout transfer switch to avoid the possibility of back-feeding the grid and endangering power company workers.

Comment: Thanks everyone! The sumo pump is 1/2 hp. And usually needs 4 hours to fully clear out all the water!

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your tolerance for failure. If you just add the listed watts and keep within the running watts listed on the label your electronics will probably brown-outs periodically, but you will survive. If you add all the numbers then double it you might never get a failure. If you wan't maximum reliability triple all the numbers for things that are primarily motors, like the sump and fridge.

Just a heads up, coffee makers are real power pigs, turn it off when you microwave something. Also it would reduce random overloads if you can turn your sump off and choose to run it when you know your other consumption is low.

With a little awareness you can usually get by with a 5000 watt, I have a 3200w that handles everything except my well. If the power outage seems serious or extended then I fire up my 5000w and just use my 3200w for my barns when needed.

Comment: One additional question - the generator will be under the carport which is detached from the house. Does anyone recommend using a chain or cord to secure the generator?

Comment: Depends on your circumstances. Where I live literally nobody would see or hear somebody breaking into my garage or barn.(County only has 22 people per square mile). Locks just make things you have to fix if they break in.